# VBA Cell address of Max()

Tags: vba, excel

I have something like

```
sdMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D2", Cells(emptyRow, 4)))
```

to find the maximum number of column D

How do I find the location of this maximum number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Defined as a user defined function in vba, returning the address as a string

```
Function AddressOfMax(rng As Range) As String
    AddressOfMax = WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0)).Address

End Function
```

Or returning a range reference

```
Function AddressOfMax(rng As Range) As Range
    Set AddressOfMax = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0))

End Function
```

these functions assume rng is one column wide

These functions can be used in the sheet
eg

```
=AddressOfMax(C:C)
```

or in vba
eg

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = AddressOfMax(Range("D2", Cells(emptyRow, 4)))
```